# Is there a quick way for brightness adjustment as "slider - without fixed range" in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10

Is there a way to quickly adjust or change brightness in windows 10 as Slider without fixed range something like from Quick Access Toolbar?

I'm really struggling to find a quick access of brightness adjustment in Windows 10. 
In Windows 8.1, brightness adjustment was very much simple and quickly  can be adjusted with slider in Panel/Quick access tool bar but whereas in Windows 10 the adjustment option was provided but only with these fixed range as `0, 25, 50, 75, 100` in Panel/Quick access tool bar. Another way is longer process by navigating to the settings and adjusting the brightness in the Display.

**In Windows 10, I want the brightness adjustment feature in quick access panel/toolbar through slider (without any fixed/pre-defined range) as similar to Windows 8.1.**

Kindly Help!